# Rails: Pass "params" using Checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

So here's the Thing:

I have a Rails App with "Productos" and "Ventas" Both resources have the same attributes on their tables and ventas has one more (quantity)... the models look like this:

```
#Producto Model

class Producto < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categorias, :join_table => :categoria_productos
  attr_accessible :color, :existencia, :nombre, :precio, :talla, :uniclave, :categoria_ids 

#Venta Model

class Venta < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cantidad, :color, :nombre, :precio, :talla, :uniclave, :producto_ids
    has_many :productos
end
```

I'm using ActiveAdmin for the Admin interface and my **/admin/venta.rb** looks like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Venta do

   form do |f|
    f.inputs "Registrar Venta" do
            f.input :cantidad
      f.input :productos, :as => :check_boxes
    end
    f.buttons
  end

end
```

The result is ALL THE PRODUCTOS are showing in the "new venta" form and I can select them, but when I create a new Venta actually, the params of "venta" save empty instead of taking the selected "producto" ones...

How can I fix this?? I want all the params of the selected "producto" to be used in the newly created "venta" fields as they share the same attributes (both models have been created with the same attributes actually)

So, ideas? ;)

Comment: shouldn't your field be `f.input :producto_ids, :as => :check_boxes` rather than `productos` as you're returning an array of product IDs rather than of product instances.

Comment: nope! My migrations where named wrongly... it has to be that way... With that code I get the name of each one of the products in a list of checkboxes as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`:categoria_ids` and `: producto_ids` must be as `:categoria_id` and `:producto_id` OR you must use the `:foreign_key` for behavior between models